# my simple regression model(by keras) doesn't work

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning

i'm beginner studying neural network.
i'm doing kaggle project - bike sharing demand.
i want to use simple neural network by keras, but loss is not decreasing.
what should i do?

-----------code--------------

```
# dataset from pandas

feature_names = ["season", "holiday", "workingday", "weather",
             "temp", "atemp", "humidity", "windspeed",
             "datetime_year", "datetime_hour", "datetime_dayofweek"]
label_name = ["count"]
X_train = train[feature_names]   #shape (10886, 11)
Y_train = train[label_name]      #shape (10886, 1)
X_test = test[feature_names]

# layers

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 50, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim=11))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units = 50, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))


model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Train
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 100, epochs = 200)
```

---------result------------

```
Epoch 1/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 4s 325us/step - loss: 69206.2478 - acc: 0.0094
Epoch 2/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 93us/step - loss: 69184.5435 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 3/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 89us/step - loss: 69181.6330 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 4/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 93us/step - loss: 69179.0222 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 5/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 91us/step - loss: 69175.7442 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 6/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 109us/step - loss: 69171.9052 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 7/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 122us/step - loss: 69171.6164 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 8/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 92us/step - loss: 69167.6923 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 9/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 91us/step - loss: 69166.2911 - acc: 0.0096
Epoch 10/200
10886/10886 [==============================] - 1s 94us/step - loss: 69164.1145 - acc: 0.0096
...
```

Comment: What happens when you increase the learning rate , because loss is decreasing if ever so slightly so maybe your lr is too small

Comment: The value of your loss suggest that your outputs are not normalized, since you use sigmoid at the output layter the output will only be in the [0, 1] range, meaning the model will never fit the data.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro omg...thank you really. i used linear as activation function. acc is not best, but i found it changes. thanks again

Comment: Accuracy is only meaningful for classification, and you are doing regression.

Comment: now I understand what you mean. @MatiasValdenegro Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the learning rate in the `model.compile` section. Start with `0.0001`, then `0.001` and `0.01` and see what happens.